# Datatables - Child Rows not opening on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am attempting to create 4 tabs with a (datatables) table in each tab - the table uses to open the tab twice, or go to another tab and then go back (without refreshing the page) I cannot open any of the child rows and it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I am struggling to figure out why!

How do I get it to let me see the child row every time?

Thanks

This is the jQuery I am using with data-tables.

```
 $('.tab-link').click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();

var table_to_get = $(this).attr('data-tab');
            if (table_to_get == "tab-2"){
        var table_name ="#restaurants_table";
      } else if (table_to_get == "tab-3"){
        var table_name ="#pubs_table"
      } else if (table_to_get == "tab-4"){
        var table_name ="#clubs_table"
      } else {
        var table_name ="#bars_table"
      }

      var userid = '<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>';
      var table = $(table_name).DataTable( {
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing" : true,
                "bServerSide" : true,
        "ajax": {
          url : "myListsql2.php",
          dataType : "json",
          type: "POST",
          "data": function ( d ) {
              d.userid = userid;
              d.table_name = table_name;
          },
          "initComplete":function( settings, json){
            console.log(json);
              console.log("DONE");
              // call your function here
          },
        },
        "columns": [
          {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "defaultContent": ''
          },
          { "data": "name" },
          { "data": "locale" },
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
      });
      var table_and_body = table_name + ' tbody';

      $(table_and_body).on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } );
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');

                $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
            }
      });
    });
```

EDIT - Format

```
function format ( d ) {

    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<div class="slider">'+
    '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Address:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Opening Times:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.opening_times+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Phone Number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.phone_number+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>'
    '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you are trying to read `name` property that doesn't exist. Either data returned by your script doesn't contain `name` property or you are trying to access `name` property in your `format()` function which you didn't post.

Also you need to move one click handler outside of another click handler as shown below.

```
$('.tab-link').click(function(e){
   // skipped
});

$('table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
   // skipped
});
```

Or remove click handler with `off()` method. For example.

```
$(table_and_body).off('click', 'td.details-control');
$(table_and_body).on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
   // skipped
});
```

Make sure your server-side script returns `name` for all tables.

Comment: Thanks! I have added my function to the question! Confused as to why it works the first time but not after that!

Comment: Perfect that works - However If in order for it work I have to keep the table tbody function inside the above div for some reason! Again can't figure out why! - Any suggestions?